# Qmailtoaster send process down

Tags: linux, email-server, email

I'm unable to get my qmailtoaster working on CentOS 5.9 64-bit:

```
[root@nowosci supervise]# qmailctl stat
authlib: up (pid 2653) 212 seconds
clamd: up (pid 2658) 212 seconds
imap4: up (pid 2663) 212 seconds
imap4-ssl: up (pid 2652) 212 seconds
pop3: up (pid 2667) 212 seconds
pop3-ssl: up (pid 2659) 212 seconds
send: up (pid 13957) 0 seconds
smtp: up (pid 2665) 212 seconds
spamd: up (pid 2655) 212 seconds
submission: up (pid 2643) 212 seconds
authlib/log: up (pid 2656) 212 seconds
clamd/log: up (pid 2666) 212 seconds
imap4/log: up (pid 2664) 212 seconds
imap4-ssl/log: up (pid 2654) 212 seconds
pop3/log: up (pid 2660) 212 seconds
pop3-ssl/log: up (pid 2657) 212 seconds
send/log: up (pid 2644) 212 seconds
smtp/log: up (pid 2661) 212 seconds
spamd/log: up (pid 2650) 212 seconds
submission/log: up (pid 2662) 212 seconds
```

Send is down. When running manually I got:

```
[root@nowosci send]# ./run
alert: cannot start: unable to switch to queue directory
```

Is there anything wrong here:

```
    [root@nowosci /]# ls -l /var/qmail/
razem 48K
drwxr-sr-x  2 alias  qmail 4,0K sty 22 17:26 alias
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:57 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 boot
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:57 control
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 doc
drwxr-xr-x 10 root   qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 man
drwxr-xr-- 12 qmailq qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 queue
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   qmail  215 sty 22 17:26 rc
drwxr-x---  3 clamav root  4,0K sty 22 17:28 simscan
drwxr-xr-x  3    201 qmail 4,0K lut  3 21:58 spamdyke
drwxr-xr-x 12 qmaill qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:57 supervise
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 users
```

or here ?

```
    [root@nowosci /]# ls -l /var/qmail/queue/
razem 40K
drwxr--r--  2 qmails qmail 4,0K sty 22 17:26 bounce
drwxr--r-- 25 qmails qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 info
drwxr--r--  2 qmailq qmail 4,0K lut 19 00:16 intd
drwxr--r-- 25 qmails qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 local
drwxr-xr--  2 qmailq qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 lock
drwxr-xr-- 25 qmailq qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 mess
drwxr--r--  2 qmailq qmail 4,0K lut 19 00:16 pid
drwxr--r-- 25 qmails qmail 4,0K lut 18 23:56 remote
drwxr-xr--  2 qmailq qmail 4,0K lut 19 00:16 todo
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root  4,0K sty 28 15:19 yanked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple, remove all qmail packages  then remove old users and groups:

```
deluser qmaillog
delgroup qmail
```

Then reinstall qmail packages and all is working ok ;)